# Editing Spring Boots application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

In spring boot, is it possible to edit the application.properties file stored in resources.

I need to change the server.port property dynamically from my program but cannot seem to write changes to the properties file.

My application is being executed from a jar built by maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate properties through command line arguments in your case it will be

```
 java -Dserver.port=your_port_number target_folder/your_final_jar_name.jar
```

this way you can change the port while starting your spring boot app.

Comment: thanks this was a better and safer solution than trying to change it while the app is running

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to override properties defined in this file. See [External Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for all the options. We mainly use either parameters that we pass on application startup (i.e. mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8080) or environment settings (i.e. SERVER_PORT=8080).